# Adding html elements to page with MVC Razor pages

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

On the html for my page I have a `<script id="pagedata"></script>` element which I would like to add an element to only if a certain partial is rendered. In my layout.cshtml I have the following:

```
@if (Brand != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_UseApp");
}
```

And in my _UseApp.cshtml:

```
@{

    var iosAppUrl = // retrieve iosLink from our CRM database
    var androidUrl = // retrieve android link from our CRM database 

    // Here I want to add the above variables to the <script id=pagedata> in the html page. Something 
    like this: 

    PageData.AddPageData("appstore", iosAppUrl);
    PageData.AddPageData("playstore", androidUrl);
```

I cannot work out how to do this - I set breakpoints in the UseApp.cshtml file and the file is being called, but I don't know how to add these script elements. I don't want to just add them into the layout file because I want to keep the app logic separate. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: @JacobHallgarth Thank you - but what to put between those script tags?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve? From your question, I understand that you want to execute JavaScript code, only if a partial view is rendered. Is  that correct?

Comment: No, @JacobHallgarth, I want to add elements to the HTML of the page only if a partial view is rendered

Comment: So you want to add HTML elements to the page when a certain partial is rendered? Or, you would like to add an attribute to the `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: When the UseApp partial is rendered, I want to add an attribute to the already existing `<script id="pagedata"></script>` page element. So it ends up as: `<script data-playstore="link" id="pagedata"></script>` instead @JacobHallgarth

Comment: Did the answer I have added help at all?

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to use jQuery, as reading HTML elements in C# is rather difficult.

In the script below, it checks if the HTML exists, and if it does, we will  assign an attribute to it. The second argument in `attr()` will be your link, note that you can use C# to get the value from your Db, by using the model or ViewBag.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { // on ready
            if ($("#replaceWithYourId").length) { // check if ID exists
                $("#pagedata").attr("data-playstore", "link") // use jQuery attr method.
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JacobHallgarth - my issue is getting the `data-playstore` attribute ON the page at all - at the moment it's not even being added.